# Symfony4: Loading fixtures from bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, bundle, fixtures

I am trying to add fixtures from a bundle to the fixtures in my application. The fixtures reside in a subdirectory in my bundle under `lib/MyCompany/MyBundle/Fixtures`.

Example:

```
// MyCompany/MyBundle/Fixtures/SpecialFixtures.php
<?php

namespace MyCompany\MyBundle\Fixtures;

use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class SpecialFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
    }
}
```

Then I use this fixture in my application as a dependency to another fixture

```
// src/Fixtures/DependentFixtures.php
<?php

namespace App\Fixtures;

use MyCompany\MyBundle\Fixtures\SpecialFixtures;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;

class DependentFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
    }

    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return array(
            SpecialFixtures::class,
        );
    }
}
```

My naive approach of using the command and expecting it works like written in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#loading-fixtures)

`./bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load`

fails with

```
Fixture "MyCompany\MyBundle\Fixtures\SpecialFixtures" was declared as a dependency, but it should be added in fixture loader first.
```

Trying to add the fixtures directory in the extension's load function also does not work, since the service `doctrine.fixtures.loader` is not defined during loading of the extension class of the bundle. Although this service shows up in the list of services in `./bin/console debug:container`.

How can I tell the fixtures loader were to find additional fixtures that are managed inside of a bundle?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

**Remark**: Heavily redacted after first comment.

Comment: > This command looks for all services tagged with doctrine.fixture.orm. If you're using the default service configuration, any class that implements ORMFixtureInterface (for example, those extending from Fixture) will automatically be registered with this tag. https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#loading-fixtures

Comment: Well, while that is written in the documentation, it apparently does not work like that, when you put the fixtures in a bundle. I see that I should have added more to the example to show the structure of my fixtures. I'll edit it. Thank you.

Comment: Try changing the class name to match the file name, `EventOptionFixtures` to `SpecialFixtures`

Comment: Thanks for the remark. It was a typo in my question not in my code.